# sql query request on codeigniter framework

Tags: sql, codeigniter

hi i want to solve this qyery in modal

```
SELECT *
FROM userinfo t1
  JOIN (SELECT value as val_pas, attribute as att_type FROM radcheck
        WHERE radcheck.username = "$username" AND radcheck.attribute LIKE "%Password") t2
  JOIN (SELECT value as val_simulate FROM radcheck
        WHERE radcheck.username = "$username" AND radcheck.attribute LIKE "Simultaneous-Use") as t3
WHERE t1.`username` = "$username"
```

thanks in advance

[the result need like this]

[image: 1]

Comment: No join conditions needed?

Comment: "solve this query in modal" doesn't mean anything to us , please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: here is the semple http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d8fb624/1